# Error: its rank is undefined, but the layer requires a defined rank

Tags: python, tensorflow, tf.keras

I have my tf.keras model feeding from a `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator` feature size `(224, 224, 1)` and label size `(1, 265)` as I have `265 CLASSES`. My batch size is `64`, returned feature size is `(64, 244, 244, 1)` and label size `(64, 265)`

below lies my training model: `IM_SIZE = (224, 224, 1)` while `DO_FINE_TUNING` has been set to `True` and `FINE_TUNE_AT = 40`

```
def model_defenition(model_type='ResNet50'):
    if model_type == 'ResNet50':
        base_model = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(
            include_top = False,
            weights='imagenet'
        )
        print(f'num layers in base model: {len(base_model.layers)}')
        base_model.trainable = DO_FINE_TUNING

        for layer in base_model.layers[:FINE_TUNE_AT]:
            layer.trainable = False

        model = tf.keras.Sequential([
            tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=IM_SIZE),
            tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=3, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same'),
            base_model,
            tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = len(CLASSES), activation=tf.nn.softmax)
        ])
        return model
model = model_defenition(model_type='ResNet50')
model.compile(optimizer=OPTIMIZER, loss=LOSS_FN, metrics=METRICS_LIST)
model.summary()
```

When I cal the model.fit function as per below

```
model.fit(
    train_ds,
    epochs=EPOCHS,
    steps_per_epoch=len(df_train)//BATCH_SIZE,
    validation_data=valid_ds,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    verbose=1,
    callbacks=CALLBACKS,
    workers=1,
    use_multiprocessing=True
)
```

I'm getting the below error

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: its rank is undefined, but the layer requires a defined rank.
```

I'm using tensorflow version 2.2.0.
Any help regarding this will be highly appreciated.
Please feel free to ask for any other part of the code to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1):

So the issue here is that the `Resnet` model also contains the `Input_layer`.

If you do the summary of the `Resnet` model you can see this.

`base_model.summary()`

```
Model: "resnet50"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_10 (InputLayer)           [(None, None, None,  0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1_pad (ZeroPadding2D)       (None, None, None, 3 0           input_10[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

So I will suggest to use the `base_model` first and then use your own layers following to the `base_model`.

Also just as a side note, do check the documentation of the `resenet` model. It says that if you use `include_top = False` then you will also have to specify the `input_shape`. This could also be the problem. Do check the API [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications/ResNet50).

I do not have the complete code so I cannot try everything from here. But I will go through those above pointers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have been able to start training.

Comment: If my answer solved your problem. I will request to up vote and mark it as accepted so that other users could benefit from this. Thank you.